# namespaces not giving expected results

Tags: xslt

I am trying to read the following XML using XSLT, but can not get the expected results.

If i remove the "xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CoreModels" namespace from the txnDetail node, then the xslt below works fine ???

What am i doing wrong ?

The input XML:

```
<TransactionRsp xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <avlBal>848.35</avlBal>
   <blkAmt>0</blkAmt>
   <txnDetail xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CoreModels">
      <a:txnDetail>
         <a:billAmount>400</a:billAmount>
         <a:txnDateTime>2012-02-23T14:35:45</a:txnDateTime>
      </a:txnDetail>
      <a:txnDetail>
         <a:billAmount>10</a:billAmount>
         <a:txnDateTime>2012-07-30T12:22:14</a:txnDateTime>
      </a:txnDetail>
   </txnDetail>
</TransactionRsp>
```

The XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version = '1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
 <root>
     <xsl:for-each select="TransactionRsp/txnDetail/txnDetail">
      <row>
        <col name="billAmount"><xsl:value-of select="billAmount"/></col>
        <col name="itemID"><xsl:value-of select="itemID"/></col>
      </row>
      </xsl:for-each>
</root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: There's no itemID under txnDetail in source xml. XSLT correct?

Comment: Define "works", by telling us what the expected result is. Also tell the actual result. Also, please check that the sample input XML you gave is correct. As given, if you remove `xmlns:a="..."`, you should get a parsing error relating to the `a` namespace prefix being used when it's not declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to qualify your XPath expressions with namespace prefix:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="TransactionRsp/txnDetail/a:txnDetail">
  <row>
    <col name="billAmount"><xsl:value-of select="a:billAmount"/></col>
    <col name="itemID"><xsl:value-of select="a:itemID"/></col>
  </row>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

**EDIT**: The namespace must be declared for your XSLT file too. Thanks to `@hcayless`'s comments below.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version = '1.0'
xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CoreModels" >
```

Comment: Assuming you've added xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CoreModels" to the xsl:stylesheet element, this is right.